# how to read all value from room data base and show into recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-room

I am using room database for storing json data from URL its working fine but while accessing data from data base to show on recyclerview its give one result at time and if i am open app second time then second object is showing, i am new in room can any one suggest me how to do this my code is.
App my pojo class.
 My Adapter Class is.

```
   recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    postsAdapter = new PostsAdapter(new ArrayList<Example>());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    addBorrowViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(AddBorrowViewModel.class);
    addBorrowViewModel.getItemAndPersonList().observe(getActivity(), new Observer<List<Example>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Example> itemAndPeople)
        {
            recyclerViewAdapter.addAll(itemAndPeople);
        }
    });
```

Comment: post your userDao interface, getAll() query

Comment: Hi, and also the code of  your `RecyclerviewAdapzer`, please.

Comment: hi @Vall0n update the please check once.

Comment: Consider reading the following codelabs: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/#5

Comment: @EpicPandaForce i did same but am not geeting all array list at a time in first time its array list size is 1 and after second time while fetching data it will incrase into 2 and so on..

Comment: @007 Hi, try without this line `recyclerviewAdpater.notifyDataSetChanged();`. As far as i know it must only be called if data changed. It seems that this is called even before the adapter with the data is set.

Comment: @Vall0n while adiding data model am geting model list one at a time can and if i run code again then am getting model size two and its size increase again and again in data model is for loop is required

Comment: any one give me suggest gyes?

Comment: @007 Again, did you try the code without with this statement `recyclerviewAdpater.notifyDataSetChanged();` removed?  And can you also  provide the complete code where you set up the recycler view and adapter?

Comment: @Vall0n as you can see i have view model class and all data store into array list now but its showing only one object data how can i iterate all object through the array list this is confusion for me.

Comment: Sry, but i don't understand your code. Where is `postsAdapter` used and where gets your `recyclerViewAdapter` initiated?

Comment: @Vall0n ok i can understand i just want to know how to iterate data using array list right now all data store in array list but its show in only one object. show in want to iterate all object.

Answer (score 1):

Follow [this](http://shaoniiuc.com/android/android-rxjava-tutorial-make-code-reactive/) or [this](http://shaoniiuc.com/android/room-persistence-library-learn-deeply/)

You didn't add LiveData in your dao. Add livedata and it will automatically return the list for you.
However

In your dao

```
@Query("select * from table_name")
public LiveData<List<Model>> getAll();
```

In your activity or fragment

```
 yourViewModel.getAll().observe(this, new Observer<List<Model>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Model> models) {
            adapter.addAll(models);
        }
    });
```

Comment: its working fine the problem is in first after open the app its showing its showing only first row only when i am open app again it will add another row and it happen every time i am in first time one, then add second row followed by one and so on...

Comment: for instance if i am open in my app then array list size is one if am open app second then array list size is 2 and its increase in every time while app open and fetch the data.

Comment: Every time new data or same data added again and again

Comment: every time new data

Comment: is here for loop require or not?